# Как на Python написать код для построения графа по матрице смежности чтобы только односторонние стрелки отображались?

Tags: python, алгоритм, матрицы, графы

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
P0= [[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]]

G = nx.DiGraph(np.matrix(P0))
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, node_size=300, arrows=True)
plt.show()
```

Если построить по этому коду то стрелки которые указывают на двух вершин тоже отображаются. А хотелось бы чтобы их не было на графе.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что-что нужно? В вершине 4 только одна входящая дуга, и стрелка в неё только одна.

Comment: Значит отредактируйте матрицу смежности, выберите какие связи/стрелки оставить.

Answer (score -1):

Параметр "arrows" изменить на False

```
    nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, node_size=300, arrows=False)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]